# Pandas Case Statement Not Showing Correct Output

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, case

I am trying to write a case statement where if the column value = 50 THEN 50 ELSE 7 into a new column. When i do this case statement -  there are certainly columns where the value is 50 but is still spitting out 7.

```
df['wattage'] = np.where(df['charge_type_2'] ==50, '50','7')
```

Comment: Are you sure to have homogeneous types in your Series? `50 != '50'`

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to compare your column to a string not to an integer:

```
df['wattage'] = np.where(df['charge_type_2'] == '50', '50','7')
#                                        HERE --^--^
```

And if you have mixed type in your column, you can cast the values as string before:

```
df['wattage'] = np.where(df['charge_type_2'].astype(str) == '50', '50','7')
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have mixed types, convert to a common one. I'd encourage you to use numbers, not string representation of numbers:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'charge_type_2': [1, '2', '50', 50]})

df['wattage'] = pd.to_numeric(df['charge_type_2'], errors='coerce').where(lambda x: x.eq(50), 7)
```

Output:

```
  charge_type_2  wattage
0             1        7
1             2        7
2            50       50
3            50       50
```

*Note that `charge_type_2` remained unconverted, you might want to replace it!*

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'test': [1,50,51,20,0,2**11]})

def check(val):
    if val == 50:
        return '50'
    else:
        return '7'
    
df['test'].apply(lambda x: check(x))
```

Output:

```
0     7
1    50
2     7
3     7
4     7
5     7
Name: test, dtype: int64
```

Maybe your problem is with your data type:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'test': [1,50,51,20,0,2**11]})

def check(val):
    if val == 50:
        return 50
    else:
        return 7
    
df['test'].astype(str).apply(lambda x: check(x))
```

In this case the output is:

```
0    7
1    7
2    7
3    7
4    7
5    7
Name: test, dtype: int64
```

More simply, use:

```
df.where(df==50, 7).astype(str)
```

again, note to the type of your data.

Comment: Why would you use `apply` here? :/

Comment: I'd like **you** not to use `apply` in such cases, you deserve better ;)

Answer (score 0):

in this case you can use from np.select , it is very faster than apply method

```py
df['wattage'] = np.select([df['charge_type_2'] ==50], ['50'], '7')
```